# WSO2 - Carbon Application Project in eclipse

Tags: wso2

I downloaded developer-studio-eclipse-jee-luna-win64-x86_64-3.8.0 from WSO2 web site and tried to create a 'Carbon Application Project'.
But 'Carbon Application Project' project type is not available in eclipse BPEL perspective. 
Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer called a "Carbon Application Project". It is now being renamed as **Composite Application Project**.

If you try to create a new Project and search under WSO2 category, you should be able to see the Distribution Sub Category. Composite Application Project is there under the Distribution Category.

Alternatively you should be able to search it using the "Composite Application Project" inside the New Project Wizard.

Please refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Packaging+Artifacts+Into+Deployable+Archives#PackagingArtifactsIntoDeployableArchives-GroupingartifactsintoaCompositeApplicationProject for official documentation.

Hope this helps!

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana

Comment: Thanks a lot Harshana. It seems I referred your old documentation in your web site.